# Facebook login trying to translate obj C to swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

can someone translate this C objective for me please

I am trying to add FBlogin to my app and I'm struggling because parses instructions are not complete. and the tutorial they have is for obj C

I am still new and teaching myself really so there are a lot of things I do not understand yet including how to use initializers and where to declare things, any help would be appreciated.

```js
self.window.rootViewController = [
  [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: [
    [LoginViewController alloc] init
  ]
];

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

im having problems with the root view controller

```js
import UIKit


@ UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {


    var window: UIWindow

    init(window: UIWindow) {

      self.window = window
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject] ? ) - > Bool {





      Parse.setApplicationId("myID", clientKey: "myKey")



      PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook()

      // Override point for customization after application launch.
      self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)


      var controller: UIViewController = UINavigationController()


      var navController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)


      self.window.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: FBLoginView.self.init())

      self.window.backgroundColor = UIColor()
      self.window.makeKeyAndVisible()

      return true

    }
```